# cancan is not calling the ability method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cancan

I want to limit the access to read the lead for a user. 
I have the relation as :
Account has many office and Account also has users. And Office has leads.
Now only the user associated with the office can view its lead.

I have defined the ability as :

```
 can :read, Lead do |lead, office|
      @office && user.account_ids.include?(@office.account_id)
 end
```

And I have this in the view :

```
- if can? :read, Lead, @office
```

but I can see that the above ability check is not being called with the view mentioned. Am I messing something here ?

Comment: Never used cancan, but the answer below should work. Hey, its nice to see a fellow Nepalese working in RoR. I'm a RoR enthusiast too. Nice to see you here. :)

Comment: I'm adding u to my gtalk list

Answer (score 0):

The code should read something like this:

```
can :read, Office do |office|
  office && user.account_ids.include?(office.account_id)
end
```

### View:

```
- if can? :read, @office
```

Comment: actually I wanted to limit the access to read the lead. your suggestion doesn't include the lead at all. I will elaborate more on the question itself.